# What does these lines of code do in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, jython

I am converting them to Jython script and I felt all it does is remove spaces at ends

```
function test (strField)
  Dim re 
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^\s*"
  re.MultiLine = False
  strField = re.replace(strField,"")
End Function
```

Comment: It locates any whitespace characters and removes them from the string variable `strField`. Can't comment on the `Fun`, `End Fun` never seen that before, would expect `Sub`, `End Sub` or `Function`, `End Function`. Maybe VBScript recognises `Fun` as short for `Function` either way the signature does not represent a `Function` you'd expect the returned value like `test = strField` if it was a `Function`.

Comment: Basically, it's a custom implementation of [`LTrim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83) that will remove not just spaces but all whitespace from the beginning of a string (the builtin `LTrim` would remove only consecutive spaces).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that's a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It uses the `RegExp` object in VBScript to check for whitespace `\s` at the start of the variable passed into the `Sub` / `Function` called `strField`. Once it identifies the whitespace it uses the `Replace()` method to remove any matched characters from the start of the string.

As [@ansgar-wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) has [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502680/what-does-these-lines-of-code-do-in-vb#comment72147575_42502680) it is just an all whitespace implementation of the [LTrim() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83).

I'm assuming this is meant to be a `Function` though *(haven't tested but maybe VBScript accepts `Fun` as shorthand for `Function`, not something I'm familiar with personally)* with that in mind it should return the modified `strField` value as the result of the function. Would also recommend using `ByVal` to stop the `strField` value after it is manipulated bleeding out of the function.

```
Function test(ByVal strField)
  Dim re 
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^\s*"
  re.MultiLine = False
  strField = re.replace(strField,"")
  test = strField
End Function
```

Usage in code:

```
Dim testin: testin = "             some whitespace here"
Dim testout: testout = test(testin)
WScript.Echo """" & testin & """"
WScript.Echo """" & testout & """"
```

Output:

```
"             some whitespace here"
"some whitespace here"
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It helped me. Also, we use Function only , not Fun.. Sorry about that.. Thanks again